# Unable to use Disk Quotas on USB external exFat drive in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, samba, usb-drive, nas, quota

UPDATE: Current fstab line is:
UUID=usb_drive_id /mnt/usb_drive1 exfat defaults,usrquota,_netdev 0 0

Thanks in advance for helping.

I set up a WD USB external drive as a NAS on Ubuntu Server 18.04 to use it as file backup server, and I also successfully set Samba server. I am planning to create as much Unix/Samba users as workstations and servers in LAN in a way that for every machine there will be a unique Samba shared folder for backup in the NAS. So far 3 users have been successfully created.

The thing is that every Samba shared folder created has only 20 GB storage capacity. I tried unsuccessfully to set Disk Quota to enable size settings on NAS for every user; the quota configuration on the external drive line in fstab is not finally applied.

CURRENT CONFIGURATIONS:
- USB External 4TB drive mounted at: /mnt/usb_drive1
- Samba shared folders at: /mnt/usb_drive1/user1 /mnt/usb_drive1/user2 and so on
- fstab line for USB external drive: UUID=usb_drive_id /mnt/usb_drive1 exfat usrquota,auto,_netdev 0 0

Regarding Quota settings, I couldn't enabled quota for USB external drive, configuration just didn't work; when I try to check quota on external drive I get:

quotacheck: Mountpoint (or device) /mnt/usb_drive1 not found or has no quota enabled.
quotacheck: Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.

mtab command shows that external drive is properly mounted.

What I need is to allow bigger capacity to Samba shared folders in order to allow data from workstations to be backed up.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

exfat is a simple file system intended for removable storage, like sd cards in camera, usb sticks and so forth.

It does not support advanced features, like user permissions (ACL), or quotas. This applies on both Windows and Linux; it is a limitation of the file system.

If you use the disk exclusively with Linux, there's no reason to use exfat. Use ext4, btrfs, xfs or some other Unix file system which supports features such as quotas and Unix ACL's.

Comment: I'm saying that quota on the file system level is simply not supported by exfat.

Comment: Deleted the comment by accident trying to edit to add more... Will resume now that you also provided your comment: According to you, Quotas is not supported by exFat on the file system level. Let's say that's correct; if I format the drive as ext4 - or any other type supported by Quotas -, would I be able to share the drive over the LAN for both Windows and Linux machines to make backups? Would I be able to set the backup server as NAS? Thanks for commenting.

Comment: The file system used *on disk* doesn't matter for the client. Samba presents the filesystem via the SMB protocol, not as a raw block device.

Comment: Understood, @vidarlo, but what if I need to unplug the USB drive and try to use it on another system / machine? Would Windows read data from the USB drive if formatted as ext4? I mean, would I be able to read / write on the USB external drive if plugged into any other machine? I would like to have backup data available at any moment, anywhere.

Comment: Windows does not read ext4 natively.

Comment: Well, I decided to format the USB external drive as ext3 or ext4 and set Ubuntu server as NAS by using Samba to create shared folders on USB drive, after all it is not meant to be used for file sharing but backup.